# Why do implicits which are defined in a separate trait after the usage result in a compile error?

Tags: scala, sbt

Why does the following code results into a compile error:

```
class MyImplicit

class FooTest extends ImplicitProvider {

  def getImplicit(implicit i: MyImplicit) = i

  getImplicit
}

trait ImplicitProvider {
  implicit val myImplicit = new MyImplicit
}
```

The compile error is:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter i: MyImplicit getImplicit
```

**If I move the trait ImplicitProvider above the class FooTest everything works fine.**

I compile with scala 2.11.7 and sbt 0.13.9.

Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a "feature". Take a look at the comments in [this ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1814).

Apparently this is expected behaviour when the type of the implicit is not explicitly specified. So you can fix it by adding a type annotation to the implicit val.

```
class MyImplicit

class FooTest extends ImplicitProvider {

  def getImplicit(implicit i: MyImplicit) = i

  getImplicit
}

trait ImplicitProvider {
  implicit val myImplicit: MyImplicit = new MyImplicit
}
```

Comment: And what's the reason for that (feature) behavior? I read something like "That way, we avoid the cyclic reference errors." which I don't understand straight away..